# SQL: Returning a list of unique values with respect to another value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that tells me the products as well as which state they're sold in.

```
PRODUCT    | STATE
-------------------------------------------------
yPhone     | Alabama
yPad       | Massachusetts
yPhone     | Alaska
yPhone     | Wyoming
yPad       | Alabama
yPhone     | California
yPad       | Florida
```

What I would like is to extract from the database is a list of every state each product is sold in as well as the count of states, grouped by the product; i.e.

```
PRODUCT    | STATE                                | COUNT(STATE)
---------------------------------------------------------------
yPhone     | Alabama, Alaska, Wyoming, California | 4
yPad       | Massachusetts, Alabama, Florida      | 3
```

Is there a way to do this in a single SELECT statement, or multiple SELECT statements?

Comment: See about aggregating functions in the manual

Comment: Hi @Strawberry, using the Count function is easy, already did this, the grouping in a list is the issue I can't seem to fix even with a GROUP BY function. Using a GROUP BY function (e.g. GROUP BY product) will only give me a single value in the state column.

Comment: Presumably that's because you haven't yet read the section on aggregating functions

Comment: How is it condescending? I simply presented the facts as I understood them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, the `GROUP_CONCAT` function can be used to get a list that's concatenated.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat